# How to call callfunc function in cocos2dx 3.0

Tags: c++11, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have to convert objective c++ to C++ 11.   I have stuck with the following syntax.
I have referred in testcpp and try the following syntax.

Here the code which i tried:

```
this->runAction
(
 Sequence::create
 (
  blink,
  CallFunc::create(CC_CALLBACK_0(Hero::stopBlinking, NULL)),    -> issue this line.
  NULL
  )
 );
```

It shows error `"no matching function for call to 'bind'" in "CallFunc::create".`
Can any one assist or help me.

Comment: You need to change NULL to the object you want the method called on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your coding, just replace the below code:

```
 CallFuncN::create(CC_CALLBACK_1(Hero::stopBlinking,this));
```

Because

```
 CallFunc can be created with an @std::function<void()>  
 CallFuncN can be created with an @std::function<void(Node*)
```

Refer:

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Release_Notes_for_Cocos2d-x_v300/diff/5

Answer (score 2):

Since I was having the same problem, it might help someone

```
CallFunc::create( std::bind(&Hero::stopBlinking,this) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following

```
    FiniteTimeAction *callAct = CallFunc::create(CC_CALLBACK_0(Hero::stopBlinking, this));
    Sequence* seq = Sequence::create(blink,callAct ,NULL);
    this->runAction(seq);
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way via lambda functions:

```
CallFuncN *callFunc = CallFuncN::create([&] (Node* node) {
    // cast node to Hero and do what you need with it
});
```

But of course, this is more suitable for short code block like:

```
node->removeFromParent();
```