# calling a function after delay in cocos2dx

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

Trying to run a function GoToGameOverScene(this) after a delay. i am getting "void value ignored as it ought to be"

```
// set up the time delay
DelayTime *delayAction = DelayTime::create(2.5f);
// perform the selector call
CallFunc *callSelectorAction = CallFunc::create(this, SEL_CallFunc(GoToGameOverScene(this)));
// run the action
this->runAction(Sequence::create(delayAction, callSelectorAction, NULL));
```

And other function looks like this:

```
void GameScreen::GoToGameOverScene(cocos2d::Ref *pSender)
{
    auto scene = GameOver::createScene();

    Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(scene);
}
```

Comment: what line? is this the exact error message or did you transcribe it? Pretty sure there's a "not" missing, as in "void value *not* ignored"

Comment: getting error on this line " CallFunc *callSelectorAction = CallFunc::create(this, SEL_CallFunc(GoToGameOverScene(this)));", and void value ignored is the exact error i am getting

Answer (score 1):

`SpriteNM->runAction(Sequence::create(DelayTime::create(1.0),CallFunc::create(std::bind(&ClassNM::MethodNM, this,IfParameter)),NULL));`

Comment: please add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
CallFunc *callSelectorAction = CallFunc::create(this, SEL_CallFunc(GoToGameOverScene(this)));
```

To

```
CallFunc *callSelectorAction = CallFunc::create(this, callfunc_selector(ClassName::GoToGameOverScene));
```

Cheers...

Comment: compiled but not able to run, it says u r project contains error(cocos2d->cocos->base directory )

Comment: CallFunc *callSelectorAction = CallFunc::create(this, callfunc_selector(GameScreen::GoToGameOverScene));

Comment: which version of cocos2dx are you using ?

Comment: if you are using cocos2dx 3.0 then check this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215804/how-to-call-callfunc-function-in-cocos2dx-3-0

Answer (score 0):

If you are using v 3.3 then you have to use it this way :

```
CallFunc *callSelectorAction = CallFunc::create(this, CC_CALLBACK_1(ClassName:GoToGameOverScene,this));
```

Where , CC_CALLBACK_1 used when your function having one arguments.

Comment: what if when you have no arguments

Comment: @Ajax-theMax  CC_CALLBACK_0    Here num 0 indicates zero arguments..   same like CC_CALLBACK_1 for one argument, CC_CALLBACK_2 for 2 argument.    So you can use CC_CALLBACK_0 when you have no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
this->runAction(Sequence::create(DelayTime::create(1.0),CallFunc::create(std::bind(&ClassName::MethodName, this,IfParameter)),NULL));
```

**OR**

```
SpriteName->runAction(Sequence::create(DelayTime::create(1.0),CallFunc::create(std::bind(&ClassName::MethodName, this,IfParameter)),NULL));
```